# How do I run all Spinach features which use a specific step?

Tags: spinach

When changing Spinach step defined in [a Spinach steps file](https://github.com/codegram/spinach#featuresstepstest_how_spinach_worksrb), it is useful to run all those features which use that step.

e.g:

- I have `step 'I have an empty array' do..`

  defined in `features/steps/test_how_spinach_works.rb`
- I would like to run `spinach` for every `.feature` file which includes:

  `I have an empty array`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you use [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/):

1. Install [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/).
2. Update your [`ack.rc`](http://beyondgrep.com/documentation/) to include Spinach features:

   ```
   --type-set=spinach=.feature`
   ```
3. Add the following to your `bashrc`:

   ```
   function ack-spinach() {
     ack --spinach --print0 -l '$1' | xargs -0 spinach
   }
   ```

You may now run all the features with:

```
$ ack-spinach 'I have an empty array'
```